# Integration with Gmail for Work

Tags: magento-1.9, email

We are moving all of our site's mail communication to Gmail for Work. The DNS settings and integration was done and Gmail seems to taken over the mail processing for all e-mails sent to our shop's addresses, except for those sent directly through Magento (sales e-mails for example).

My guess is that the problem is due to the fact that Magento's e-mails use PHP SMTP functions, and those work directly with mail server which is on the same domain as the site. So when the mail server gets the message, it recognises the same domain, and processes the mail by itself, and because of it no e-mails are pushed to Google, but instead, we still get them in the old way.

I'm not sure how to fix this? Should I do it on the application level, through Magento classes, or to try and fix some PHP setting for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SMTP Pro Extension](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) by Ashley Schroder. It also has default settings for using the Gmail SMTP server.

[image]